# Intent filter for filtering payment sending apps

Tags: android, android-intent, payment, intentfilter, google-pay

How do I filter apps that supports payment when sending user to another app for payment?

showPaymentSupportedApps();

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {showPaymentSupportedApps(); } });

void showPaymentSupportedApps(){ // do some magic here }
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be trying to filter the list of apps yourself. Instead, you should let the operating system handle it for you: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#no-app-available

Example:

```
// Build the intent.
val location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+California")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location)

// Try to invoke the intent.
try {
    startActivity(mapIntent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    // Define what your app should do if no activity can handle the intent.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want payment apps to be listed not location (map) apps. 

Comment: I don't know about the payment apps that you are referring to. But try looking into whether or not the payment apps you want to support have their own URI scheme. For example, payments in India support the `upi:` URI scheme.